# Getting result from db using WHERE ALL

Tags: sql, database

Him I need help with writing sql sql query. For example I have two tables. Students and marks.

**First table consist of student_id ,name,address, phone ....**

**Second table include such columns : mark_id,student_id, subject_id , mark_value and date**

So I need to get information about students that have only marks of one type (for instance only A or C).
For example student Stuart has got 5 marks and all of them are A so I need get information about this student.

I must use ALL or ANY statement.

Please explain how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `... WHERE 'A' = ALL (SELECT mark_value ...)`

Comment: which version of RDBMS? mysql or sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is Mysql.

```
 select * from student s
 where <grade > = ALL ( select mark_value from marks m where m.student_id = s.student_id )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer this works but if some student has no marks at all it is also returns him in result. I guess this issue of working ALL statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.Name, S.Student_ID, M.Mark_Value
FROM Student AS S
JOIN Marks AS M ON S.Student_ID = M.Student_ID
WHERE M.Mark_Value = ALL(SELECT Mark_Value
                         FROM Marks
                         WHERE Student_ID = S.Student_ID)
GROUP BY S.Student_ID, S.Name, M.Mark_Value
```